# Delete columns from a table that have Headers only

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, excel-tables

I have a table that has many columns (includes autofiltered headers) and some of the columns have just the header with no other data following withink that column. I want to remove those columns from my named table.

Comment: What have you  tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To delete a column, select the entire column of the spreadsheet. Then right click with the mouse on the selected column, and select "Delete".

[image]

Note that pressing Delete on the keyboard will only delete the content and not remove the column completely.

Be careful, this method removes the  entire column of the spreadsheet so the data under the table will be effected as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I was actually looking for vba code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for you , next time try to code something

```
Public Sub teste()
    Call DeleteTableColumnNull("table")
End Sub
Public Sub DeleteTableColumnNull(ByVal TableObjectName As String)
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim st As Worksheet
    Dim cols As Range
    Dim col As Range
    Dim rows As Range
    Dim row As Range



    For Each st In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If tableExistInThisSheet(st, TableObjectName) Then
            Set table = st.ListObjects(TableObjectName)
            For Each col In table.Range.Columns
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(col) = 1 Then
                    col.Delete
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Public Function tableExistInThisSheet(st As Worksheet, TableObjectName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo f
    Dim tb As ListObject
    Set tb = st.ListObjects(TableObjectName)
    tableExistInThisSheet = True
    Exit Function
f:

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, Ronan I have been using code to try and remove my "null" columns and nothing seems to work. I have only been coding for a couple of months so I know it's something that I need to learn. I tried your code but it doesn't and I don't get any errors. Suggestions?

Comment: Null is differente them Blank Cells , i am using CountA do count if there is no cells Blank = ""  , If is = "NULL" it wont work